# function view in controller codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on the news section example as demonstrated in the link below:
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/tutorial/news_section.html

It contains two functions in the controller index and view.
When I remove the view function from my controller even then I get the same output. Can any one of you help me understanding the need of function view in the controller?

```
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('news_model');
    }

   public function index()
   {
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
        $data['title'] = 'News archive';

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    public function view($slug)
    {
        $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);

        if (empty($data['news_item']))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }


}
```

Comment: Both codeigniter version of user guides can be found here now. http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How CodeIgniter URLS work is the following:

```
example.com/controller/method/param1[/param2...]
```

<sub>From: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/urls.html</sub>

When you go to `yoursite.com/news`, it automatically runs the `index()` function.  But, what if you went to `yoursite.com/news/view/1234`?

Then it would run your `view()` function and pass `'1234'` as a parameter (`$slug`).

Comment: so you are saying it is just to display the right things if 1234 exists ?